# Sorting on GUID SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

What is the best way to sort records on Guid.  Below never gives right results.

```
    With UIDs As (--                        
            Select ID =  1, UID = NEWID() 
    Union   Select ID =  2, UID = NEWID()
    Union   Select ID =  3, UID = NEWID()
    Union   Select ID =  4, UID = NEWID()
    Union   Select ID =  5, UID = NEWID()
    Union   Select ID =  6, UID = NEWID()
    Union   Select ID =  7, UID = NEWID()
    Union   Select ID =  8, UID = NEWID()
    Union   Select ID =  9, UID = NEWID()
    Union   Select ID = 10, UID = NEWID()
    Union   Select ID = 11, UID = NEWID()
    Union   Select ID = 12, UID = NEWID()
    Union   Select ID = 13, UID = NEWID()
    Union   Select ID = 14, UID = NEWID()
    Union   Select ID = 15, UID = NEWID()
    Union   Select ID = 16, UID = NEWID()
)
Select * From UIDs Order BY  UID, ID
```

Instead using Guid, how can i generate Sequential Integers in my select.

Thanks

Comment: **1.** What do you mean it doesn't give the right result. In What way? **2.** What does the last line mean "Instead using Guid, how can i generate Sequential Integers in my select." ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't is the best answer.

This explains how SQL Server: [How are GUIDs sorted by SQL Server?](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alberto_ferrari/archive/2007/08/31/how-are-guids-sorted-by-sql-server.aspx)

You have [NEWSEQUENTIALID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx) but this is [not guaranteed](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=475131) to sort as you expect. And why use a GUID when you have ranking functions?

Comment: May be so, but I'm debugging, and trying to find a specific key in the database, and want to sort my rows by their GUID ID alphabetically, so the most upvoted answer was in fact what I needed :) But you're right, don't use it outside of such an application.

Comment: @gbn you have a broken link. is this the new address? https://www.sqlbi.com/blog/alberto/2007/08/31/how-are-guids-sorted-by-sql-server/#

Answer (score 29):

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable 
ORDER BY CAST(myGuid AS VARCHAR(36))
```

Comment: use with the knowledge that wrapping a column in a function hides it from the execution plan creation process and will usually cause a full scan of the table.